# Show some message when service return null in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

Service contains following code snippet:

```
if (lstSite != null && lstSite.Count > 0)
{
    csvBytes = ExportListToCSV(lstSite.Select(x => new { x.User,  
                        x.Date, x.Action, x.Data }).ToList(), ",");
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType="text/csv";
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers["Content-Disposition"]  
     = "attachment; filename=\"Report_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-
                               MM-dd-HH:mm") + ".csv\"";
    return new MemoryStream(csvBytes);
}
else
{
    return null; //Show some message like alert("No Data Found.");
}
```

When service contains data, this will export excel on the browser, but if it is null, it shows nothing.
so can we show some message on else part. Actually i have used page `<Form action="CallToService">` tag to call service, so CSV generate on the page itself. No way to catch service response and show some message.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is:

on the page where you are calling this service.

store the result in some variable

```
  var ResultSet= Service.YourFunction();
```

and then check if the returned data is null or not

```
  if(ResultSet==null)
  {
   // this will show alert message
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, typeof(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),     "alert('Your message');", true);

  }
```

Comment: Ok, but i am using Form tag to call service as 
`<form id="Export" name="Export" runat="server" method="post" action="../Services/Service.svc/Export">` in that how can i store the result?